# jQuery find and append element

Tags: jquery, variables, append, clone

I created a variable to find 'img' and clone like this:

```
var element = jQuery.find('img').clone();
element.appendTo('body');
```

It doesn't work for me. My Chrome console tells me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'clone'
```

Is it even possible to write `jQuery.find()` like that? What else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` requires a starting point which you haven't provided. Syntax of `jQuery.find()` is incorrect. Proper syntax for `find()` is :

```
jQuery(parentSelector).find(descendentSelector);
```

This will search within the `parentSelector` for the `descendentSelector`.

Comment: not really, you can use `$.find`.. the documents root will be your starting point

Comment: @udidu makes no sense to use `find()` on the document, you would simply use `$(selector)`

Comment: @udidu  http://jsfiddle.net/fa8uf/   throws error. What you are suggesting is undocumented. So regardless of whethter it works or not it is still bad practice to use undocumented methods that may break in future

Comment: you didn't read my answer "The clone() function not working well on the find() results, you can wrap the find() result with jQuery object": http://jsfiddle.net/fa8uf/1/

Comment: @udidu and what is the point of doing that, instead of using the method properly to start with?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use

```
$('img').appendTo('body');
```

or

```
$('img').clone().appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clone()` function not working well on the `find()` results, you can wrap the `find()` result with jQuery object like so:

```
var element = jQuery(jQuery.find('img')).clone();
element.appendTo('body');
```